# Is it possible to travel from Brazil to Peru or Colombia, by bus, without entering Bolivia?

Tags: buses, brazil, peru, colombia

I want to arrive in Peru or Colombia from Brazil, by bus.

I am wondering if there is an easy & safe way to arrive by bus in Peru, without entering Bolivia?

If not, is it possible to go to Colombia by bus?

---

Rome2Rio doesn't seem to have a solution for this.

#### Brasil → Peru

[image]

#### Brazil → Colombia

[image]

Comment: Can you get by bus to Asuncion, and then over the Chile? It may be more roundabout, but doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

It's not the only option, but the obvious choice is Ormeno's direct connection between Rio / Sao Paulo and Lima. It's a bit of a long ride, at around 4 full days of travel.

Here's the [Ormeno](http://www.grupo-ormeno.com.pe) website. Here's [my experience](https://babakfakhamzadeh.com/this-is-the-longest-bus-ride-in-the-world/) of doing that trip from Lima to Rio.
I'm not aware of being able to buy a ticket for this connection online. You'd have to go to one of Ormeno's offices. The price in 2017, for a one-way, was around 285 USD.

From Rio, the trip takes you to Sao Paulo and then, all within Brazil, to Acre, in the Far Western corner of the country. The bus then enters Peru in the country's southeastern corner, continuing to Lima via Cusco.

In Lima, you can take another Ormeno bus that directly gets you to Colombia, via Ecuador. Off the top of my head, they connect to both Medellin and Bogota.

(Alternatively, you could travel via Argentina and Chile, or skip Peru and go to Colombia via Manaus, but both are even more of a hassle.)

Comment: Wowow, I love that. Actually I’d like to arrive in Cusco! Checking their website now.

Comment: The Ormeno website is a bit of a mess, but, last time I checked, they did mention their long distance connections.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes it is possible. But you are not going to like it.**

There is [a bus connection from Sao Paulo, Brazil to Santiago Chile](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/S%C3%A3o-Paulo/Santiago), going through  Paraguay and Argentina, which does not enter Bolivia. Once there you can take [a bus from Santiago, Chile to Bogota Columbia](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Santiago/Colombia), passing through Peru and Equador.

These trips take approximately 2.5 days and 4 days respectively, so you are looking at more than a week of travelling to do it - unsurprisingly since you are traversing most of the continent. There may be places further north in Chile where you can connect, but since I assume this isn't a viable option I haven't bothered to research in more detail.

Your problem of course is that land transport does not pass through the Amazon basin, so all buses Sao Paulo-> Columbia must travel up the West of the continent. Since Bolivia borders the Amazon, avoiding Bolivia means you need to stay south of it, which means you have to traverse Chile.

Flying would not only be faster and easier, but almost certainly cheaper than this.

Comment: Neither you or the OP mention it, but it's probably relevant that Rome2Rio says that the Sao Paulo to Lima route by bus would normally be 2 days 18 hours. So this would be roughly 2 times as long or more

Comment: I can tell you that Sao Paulo to Lima is more than 2 days and 18 hours. If my memory serves me well, it's a *scheduled* four days.